# What subjects did talmud censoring involve and how far back does it go?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, publications

I'm aware of censoring of the name Yeshu, in the soncino printing of the talmud where they replaced it with "sinners of israel" in Gittin 57a.

I'm interested what other subjects or names were censored.

And also, i'm interested if there is any censoring, that we are aware of, prior to the Soncino printing, as i'm interested in how far back the censoring goes.

Comment: So that you're aware, the Soncino Talmud is considerably older than the Vilna Talmud. (The Soncino Talmud was printed in the 15th-16th century, and the Vilna Talmud was printed in the 19th).

Comment: @ShimonbM thanks, i've corrected that now

Comment: see http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4170-censorship-of-hebrew-books